# Smoother rendering performance for svg animations

Tags: html, css, svg, d3.js

I found a really good data visualization example on the web at

http://slodge.com/teach/, which makes really good use of d3js (d3js.org)

I'm looking to adapt this example with a large dataset that I have, around 1600 entities.
When I load the page with this amount of data, the rendering starts to really slow down and you can notice the lag. I've tried lowering the radius for each circle, but the animations are still slow.

Are there any techniques to improve the rendering performance?

Comment: You can try to use Canvas instead of SVG if you don't need interactivity.

Comment: 1600 circle elements should, in themselves, not be a problem in svg rendering. I'd like to see how each circle is created. Could you do that? thx